# Convert all datetime elements in list to date?

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime

The list has datetime elements along with other.

```
(1127, 1, 2, datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 8, 30), 'America/NewYork', None,     None, datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(9999, 12, 31, 0, 0), 62, 3, ' ', 2, datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 6, 16, 4, 25, 233000))
```

I tried using with no luck

```
i = [d.date() for d in i]
```

Comment: So what is your expected output? Should `i` contain **just** the dates, or the other objects too?

Comment: All the other object too. So expected output `(1127, 1, 2, 1900-01-01, 'America/NewYork', None,     None, 1970-01-01, 9999-12-31,62, 3, ' ', 2,2017-12-26,233000)`

Answer (score 0):

Just test for the object type then, in a conditional expression:

```
[d.date() if isinstance(d, datetime.datetime) else d for d in i]
```

This produces a list with *all* the values in there, with the `datetime` objects replaced with dates:

```
>>> [d.date() if isinstance(d, datetime.datetime) else d for d in i]
[1127, 1, 2, datetime.date(1900, 1, 1), 'America/NewYork', None, None, datetime.date(1970, 1, 1), datetime.date(9999, 12, 31), 62, 3, ' ', 2, datetime.date(2017, 12, 6)]
```

If you wanted to have *just* the dates, use a filter:

```
[d.date() for d in i if isinstance(d, datetime.datetime)]
```

Now we are filtering, so only the dates remain:

```
>>> [d.date() for d in i if isinstance(d, datetime.datetime)]
[datetime.date(1900, 1, 1), datetime.date(1970, 1, 1), datetime.date(9999, 12, 31), datetime.date(2017, 12, 6)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude non-datetimes by adding an if statement to your list comprehension to check if the value is an instance of datetime:

```
dates = [d.date() if isinstance(d, datetime.datetime) else d for d in i ]
```

This will keep all data, only changing datetimes. If you want to filter out non-datetimes:

```
dates = [d.date() for d in i if isinstance(d, datetime.datetime)]
```

It took me a year or two of playing with Python before I learned you could add conditions to comprehensions. It's extremely useful! See here:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-list-comprehensions-in-python-3

The article is about Python 3, but in most cases it works exactly the same in Python 2.7.